# Obtain min and max lat,long for all geometries using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, latitude-longitude, shapely

I am reading a shapefile of a county and need to extract the min and max coordinates across all geometries. It seems like this is possible with each individual geometries in the shapefile with `shapely` but not across all geometries in shapefile.

```
sf_shp = os.getcwd() + '/data/map/San_Mateo/SAN_MATEO_COUNTY_STREETS.shp'
sfgeodata = gpd.read_file(sf_shp)

sfgeodata.total_bounds <-- for bounding box.
```

Is there a property or a function to obtain this info in GeoPandas or any other packages?

Comment: Good news: Shapefile includes a header record property with the layer envelope (4D). Bad news: It doesn't have to be correct.

Comment: GDAL/OGR can give the extent of a layer directly with GetExtent https://gdal.org/doxygen/classOGRLayer.html#a3be658ddb5b33d1ed95c31286774bbd2

Answer (score 5):

You can apply bounds to each row, create a list of tuples [(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), (xmin, ...] and use itemgetter to find overall min and max:

```
import datetime as dt
import geopandas as gpd
from operator import itemgetter
start = dt.datetime.now()

df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/my_riks.shp')
bounds = df.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.bounds).tolist()

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = min(bounds, key=itemgetter(0))[0], min(bounds, key=itemgetter(1))[1], max(bounds, key=itemgetter(2))[2], max(bounds, key=itemgetter(3))[3] #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145368/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python
print(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
print('Processing time: {0} seconds'.format((dt.datetime.now()-start).seconds))

#245209.174 6111275.67 921093.74 7671055.56
#Processing time: 14 seconds
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is use [total_bounds](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds.html) method:

```
bounds = gdf.total_bounds
```

It is going to give you the values that you want.

The result will be the same even if you get the bounds of each geometry.